# ASPNETZERO - Lookup modal - How to return selected data to parent modal

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I learned from the code used in the organization units views for the user "lookup" modal and recreated it for my entity "company".

Please note, I did **not** create a new lookup modal view for my entity. I am using the standard default lookup modal view provided by ABP.

On many of the other entities in my app, they all use company, on my create/edit modals. So to test this out, I replaced a dropdown for company with a textbox with a search icon that pops open the lookup modal with all companies. 
[image]
[image]
Then once the user selects a row from the company lookup modal, I want to fill the textbox on the create modal with the selected value. The JS code shown below is doing everything I want. The only part I cannot seem to figure out is how to pass the "Selected" name and value back to my create modal form.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

      var _companyLookupModal = app.modals.LookupModal.create({
        title: app.localize("SelectACompany"),
        serviceMethod: abp.services.app.nursingOpsLookup.find_Companies
    });

  $("#btnTest").click(function (){
      _companyLookupModal.open({
          title: app.localize('SelectACompany')
      }, function (selectedItems) {
          //Below is not working, as I assume I am inside the lookup modal
          $("#CompanyId").val(selectedItems.value);
          $("#CompanyName").val(selectedItems.name);
      });
    });  



});
```

Things I have tried:

- Using the abp event bus and setting a trigger.
- Setting the selected values into a cookie using the JS code below.

  ```
  localStorage.setItem('selCmpName', selectedItems.name); //Save
  var selCmpName = localStorage.getItem('selCmpName'); //fetch
  ```

Neither of the above methods worked. Can someone tell me how to get the values back to my create modal?

Answer (score 0):

you need to return something like this, otherwise `selectedItems` will be null.

```
public async Task<PagedResultDto<NameValueDto>> Find_Companies(FindCompaniesInput input)
{        
    //filter your companies by the input and return NameValueDto within PagedResultDto

    return 
        new PagedResultDto<NameValueDto>(
        companiesCount,
        companies.Select(x => new NameValueDto(x.Name, x.Id.ToString())).ToList());           
}
```

---

Your input must be derived from `PagedAndFilteredInputDto`

```
public class FindCompaniesInput : PagedAndFilteredInputDto
{
    //your filters...      
}
```

Comment: selectedItems is not null. That is not the issue. Problem is with saving the values into my create Modal, which is launching the lookup Modal.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the result before closing the modal:

```
app.modals.SomeModal = function () {
    var _modalManager;

    this.init = function (modalManager) {
        _modalManager = modalManager;
    };

    this.save = function () {
        _modalManager.setResult('hello world');
        _modalManager.close();
    };
}
```

Setting the result will trigger the callback function and in this example will print 'hello world'.

```
SomeModal.open(
    {},
    function (callback) {
        console.log(callback);
    }
);
```